# How to pass user inputs for a java program in powershell script

Tags: java, powershell, user-input, prompt

I have a java program abc.java which prompts the user for some input. Now I am calling this java file in my powershell script. When I am executing the powershell, it comes to the prompt for the input. So now how can I enter the user input here?

My powershell script is as follows:

```
cd 'C:\LDAP\test1'
java abc
```

The output of the above run is as follows:

```
PS C:\> C:\LDAP\sample.ps1
Enter the prefix:
```

Now how to enter the value? I am ok with either entering the input during the runtime or even hardcode the input in the powershell script.

```
System.out.println("Enter the prefix:"); 

String strPrefix = objScanner.nextLine(); 

System.out.println("Enter the Country:"); 

String strLocation = objScanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: When run from `powershell`, no longer appear `prompt`? And also, can you show use the code?

Comment: The prompt appears. But while running from powershell, I can't enter the input when the prompt comes. 

Actually when the java program runs, it keeps asking for prompts and the user can enter that. So how to do that while running the java program as part of the powershell script run?

Comment: In this case I think showing us the code, will help us to help you.

Comment: You mean to say the Java code ?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the java code

Comment: Here is the Java code: 


   System.out.println("Enter the prefix:");   
   String strPrefix=objScanner.nextLine();   
   System.out.println("Enter the Country:");   
   String strLocation=objScanner.nextLine();

Comment: Next time please update the answer with code. As I can see your code. When you need to enter the value, simply click in prompt and start to type what you want to send to your code and press enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote abc.java like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;        

class abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner objScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the prefix:"); 
            String strPrefix = objScanner.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println("Prefix is \"" + strPrefix + "\"");

            System.out.print("Enter the Country:"); 
            String strLocation = objScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Country is \"" + strLocation + "\"");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And my powershell seems as follows.

```
PS C:\> C:\LDAP\sample.ps1
Enter the prefix:Mr
Prefix is "Mr"
Enter the Country:America
Country is "America"
```

If you use

```
System.out.println("Enter the prefix:");
```

and

```
System.out.println("Enter the Country:");
```

,powershell seems as follows.

```
PS C:\> C:\LDAP\sample.ps1
Enter the prefix:
Mr
Prefix is "Mr"
Enter the Country:
America
Country is "America"
```